# Show only if user-role is subscriber AND site visitor (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, intersection, adsense, user-roles

I am a bit stuck with the code below for my Wordpress site:

```
<?php
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $allowed_roles = array('subscriber', 'visitor');
     if ( array_intersect($allowed_roles, $user->roles ) ) echo '<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>' ?>
```

I want the Adsense code only be shown in the HEAD section for site visitors and the user role SUBSCRIBER. I tried 'visitor' but that didn't worked.

I don't know how to apply "array_diff" in this situation to display the Adsense code in the header for SITE VISITORS and SUBSCRIBER role?

Comment: Visitor isn't a role. So if you modified this slightly out would work with your original concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "subscriber" you can use function [current_user_can](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/)

For guests you can use function [is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/)

```
if ( current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) || !is_user_logged_in()) {
           // echo your adsense code
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is visitor does not exist. On the internet there's only a 'if logged in' check. The adsense code must only show if user role is SUBSCRIBER and for normal site visitors.

Comment: @Huxtable Visitor is the unlogged user?

Comment: @Huxtable Could you explain more about the role "visitor"?

Comment: visitor is someone who visits my site while logged out.

Comment: @Huxtable I changed the code in answer. Could you try a new code?

Comment: Thanks for the support Valerij, so this is the code?

`<?php
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) || !is_user_logged_in()) {
echo '<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXX" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>' 
} ?>`

Comment: @Huxtable Yeap. Without "$user = wp_get_current_user(); "

Comment: I'm getting the following error code "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ';' or ',' in ..." @valerii-vasyliev

Comment: @Huxtable <?php if ( current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) || !is_user_logged_in()) { echo '<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXX" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>';  } ?>

Comment: @Huxtable You missed ";" after 'echo "your-code" '

Comment: thank you so much can I send you a small donation on PayPal to show appreciation for your help?

Comment: @Huxtable No money needed. This site helped me when and I just give my debt to this site. You can vote for my answer and mark my answer "accepted".

Comment: you're an angel without wings. Marked as solved and upvoted  your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [Site Kit plugin by Google](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-site-kit/) to insert your ad code there is an option to restrict the ads snippet to users who can write posts. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I prefer to use Ads Inserter.